# Oracle Database: 11gR2 Alter Database Link, what kind user privilege it needs?

Tags: oracle, oracle11gr2

I am trying to do following to alter a database link to a new password in 11gR2.02,

alter database link dblink_name connect to db_account identified by new_password;

but it give a permission error as ORA-01031. Above statement ran in the schema which owns this database link, and also this schema has created this db link, so this schema has create db link privilege. I checked all the permissions, there is no alter database link privilege to grant in 11gR2, so what I am missing here in order to run above statement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will require the `ALTER DATABASE LINK` or `ALTER PUBLIC DATABASE LINK` system privilege to perform. See the [ALTER DATABASE LINK](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/ALTER-DATABASE-LINK.html) article under "Prerequisites". According to the documentation, you can't alter a password with this command anyway, you have to drop and re-create the link.

Answer (score 0):

Just wan to add, in the em GUI, there is no alter database link system privilege to select to grant to a user, but when I ran the command in sqlplus as following,
grant alter database link to userabc;
The moral of the story is, don't trust em 100% (maybe em version is behind), and for the new feature, run command from sqlplus to give privilege instead of relying on em drop down boxes for those 11gR2 new features.